# Keith-Wood Countdown count up after reaching 0

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

I'm using  [Keith Wood Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) in order to display timer in my page. What i want is:  start counting up when the counter reaches 0.

I can easily start the counter using until:

```
$('.digits').countdown({ until: tempsbefore, onTick: watchCountdown,alwaysExpire:true,format: 'DHMS',onExpiry: liftOff });
```

I tried to add this `$('.digits').countdown({ since: tempsbeforemeetingends,format: 'DHMS'});` to the `liftOff` method but it doesn't work. Here is the code

```
function liftOff() { 

            var tempsbeforemeetingstart=<%=Temps_Avant_Seance%>
            console.log(tempsbeforemeetingstart)
            //$('.digits').countdown('destroy');
            $('.digits').countdown({ since: tempsbeforemeetingstart,format: 'DHMS'});
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean - is it failing to run, or doing the wrong thing? What's being output in place of `<%=Temps_Avant_Seance%>`?

Comment: It's still showing the counter with 0days 0hours 0 minutes 0secondes. `<%=Temps_Avant_Seance%>` has `-1120` as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I needed to call the countdown `option` parameter  in the `liftOff` function instead of initializing it again.

```
function liftOff() { 

     $('.digits').countdown('option', {since: tempsecoule});
    }
```